# SearchView in ListView search also by "hidden" keywords

Tags: android, listview, search, keyword, searchview

I would like to ask you for some pointers where to look for solution of my problem, since googling for past few hours didn't help.

I have a `SearchView` and `ExpandableListView` and everything works fine. 
To each of my listings (`String`s) I would like to add keywords that would not be displayed, but would be searchable.

For example if we have a list of fruit:

```
-Apple
-Banana 
-Orange
```

...

I would like to assign them hidden keywords like:

```
-Apple (healthy)
-Banana (tasty)
-Orange (sour)
```

So when I would type into my `SearchView`: "healthy" it would only display Apple.

Some of my code (`SearchView`):

```
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
  search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
  search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
  search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
  search.setOnCloseListener(this);
```

and `ArrayList`:

```
  ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
  Fruit fruit = new Fruit("Apple", R.drawable.apple);
  fruitList.add(fruit);
  fruit = new Fruit("Orange", R.drawable.orange);
  fruitList.add(fruit);
  fruit = new Fruit("Banana", R.drawable.banana);
  fruitList.add(fruit);

  Basket basket = new Basket("Yes",basketList);
  basketList.add(basket);

  fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
  Fruit fruit = new Fruit("Peach", R.drawable.peach);
  fruitList.add(fruit);
  fruit = new Fruit("Pineapple", R.drawable.pineapple);
  fruitList.add(fruit);
  fruit = new Fruit("Coconut", R.drawable.coconut);
  fruitList.add(fruit);

  Basket basket = new Basket("No",basketList);
  basketList.add(basket);

  ...
```

Comment: where is a problem class: `Fruit { name, attr }` pseudocode:  `List<Fruit> searchByNameOrAttr(List<Fruit> input, string lookingFor) { return input.selectAll(x=>x.name.similarTo(lookingFor) || x.attr.similarTo(lookingFor)); }`  similarTo can be startsWith or contains and `x=>x.name ...` means  Comparator<T> implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

You need to show the implementation you have for that.  Basically, it's going to be calling this function:

```
 @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
    // IMPLEMENT HERE
 }
```

And that's where you'd handle things.  Instead of just checking the query against the name, you'd also check the "hidden" keywords, which would probably be in the Fruit class.